# How can I recreate this circle in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I have spent too much time trying to understand how to recreate this loader, but there's a gap in my knowledge. I can create a circle with a cut-out just fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to taper the line, as well as have rounded ends.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [gif](https://i.imgur.com/Ay4JosX.gifv)! And here's a step-by-step:

1. First, create a single circle and turn off the fill.
2. Double click the circle so you can edit its vector handles.
3. Add handles (click on the path) where you want the gap to start.
4. Then use the scissor tool (Layer > Path > Scissors) to remove that section of the path
5. Select the entire path and duplicate it (Edit > Duplicate)
6. Select the new duplicate path and Option-drag it smaller or larger than your original path.
7. Select both paths (Shift-click) and Join them (Layer > Path > Join)
8. Now that your two partial circles are a single path, double click into it and close the path.
9. Now you should have a single closed path in the shape of a C. Pretty much everything from here on out will require you to be in vector editing mode.
10. On one of the two short segments of the path, add a new vector point at the midpoint.
11. Change the point type to Disconnected and drag the handles to mimic the relevant handles of the points surrounding it.
12. Deleted the handles on either side of your new point. You should now have the "tail" of your circle.
13. On the other side (the other short segment of the path), add a new point at the midpoint.
14. Drag its handles out to the surrounding points
15. Now on the other side(s) of those existing/surrounding points, add two points the same distance as that midpoint point.
16. Now delete the original two corner points and, voila!, you should have the rounded "head" of your circle.
17. Adjust other points as needed to get a smooth taper around the
     whole circle.

I'm sure that's all clear as mud... let me know if you have questions.